# Consider a particle of reduced mass $\mu$ orbiting in a central force with $U=kr^n$ where $kn>0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, many-body

> Consider a particle of reduced mass $\mu$ orbiting in a central force with $U=kr^n$ where $kn>0$.
>
> **(a)** Explain what the condition $kn>0$ tells us about the force. Sketch the effective potential energy $U_{eff}$ for the cases that $n=2, -1, \text{and} -3$.
>
> **(b)** Find the radius at which the particle (which given angular momentum $l$) can orbit at a fixed radius. For what values of n is this circular orbit stable? Do your sketches confirm this conclusion?
>
> **(c)** For the stable case, show that the period of small oscillations about the circular orbit is $\tau_{osc}=\frac{\tau_{orb}}{\sqrt{n+2}}$. **Argue that if $\sqrt{n+2}$ is a rational number, these orbits are closed. Sketch them for the cases that n=2,-1 and 7**.

I have solved (a) and (b), but I trapped in (c).

For (a), I know that $kn>0$ means the force is a central force and its direction point to the origin. For the cases that $n=2, -1, \text{and} -3$, I drew the graph, as follows,

[image]

For (b), the effective potential energy is $U_{eff}=kr^n+\frac{l^2}{2\mu r^2}$ and taking a derivative with respect to $r$, I got $\frac{dU_{eff}}{dr}=knr^{n-1}-\frac{l^2}{\mu r^3}$. According to  $\frac{dU_{eff}}{dr}=0$, we knew the particle can orbit at a fixed radius $knr_0^{n+2}=\frac{l^2}{\mu}$.And then, I got that when $n>-2$, this circular orbit is stable by calculating $\frac{d^2U_{eff}}{dr^2}$ at $r=r_0$.

For (c) I got the result $\tau_{osc}=\frac{\tau_{orb}}{\sqrt{n+2}}$ by using that $\mu \ddot{r}=-\frac{dU_{eff}}{dr}$ and Taylor series at $r_0$. But I have no idea how to justify the conditions which closed orbits need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For c) You should think about what it means that an orbit is closed. It means that after some time $t$ the particle will return to it's original position.

For this to happen $m_1\tau_{osc}$ and $m_2\tau_{orb}$ have to be equal for some integer values of $m_1$ and $m_2$. This can only happen in your example if $\sqrt(n+2)$ is rational.

Comment: Could be more detailed?